# finding which auto generated input was changed/button pressed - updated

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a PHP&mySQL code that generates a html table with an input field and button that have unique names . here is the code that does that:

```
echo     "<input type=\"hidden\"name=\"id_$num\" 
        value=".$row['idSales']."><tr><td>".$row['idSales'].
        "</td><td>". $username.
        "</td><td>". $row['product'].
        "</td><td>". $row['productAmount'].
        "</td><td>". $row['dateOfPurchase'].
        "</td><td>". $row['userAddress'].
        "</td><td><a href=\"$eLink\">". $eLink .
        "</a></td><td>
        <input type=\"text\" name=\"status_$num\" class=\"input\" value=".$row['productStatus']. ">
        <input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit_$num\" value=\"submit\" class=\"button\"></td></tr>" ;
```

*(the code is looped to produce each table line)*

the table is in a form that when a button is pressed, a code in another file is triggered(action="...")

what I've tried to do is in order to find which button was pressed is this:

```
   $num = -1;
while(!isset($_POST["submit_$num"])){

    $num = $num +1;

    if(isset($_POST["status_$num"])){
        $status = $_POST["status_$num"];
        $id = $_POST["id_$num"];   
    }
```

**The problem:**
my website doesn't stop loading which I assume means that the loop is endless.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to find the pressed button? maybe my method works but I have a syntax error?

<s>2. Does the $_POST function work on non input types? will the $_POST pull the id?</s>

Thanks!

**Edit:Update**
Thank you all for answering, I fixed the errors you told me I had and updated the code in the post above, although the loop continues to loop infinitely, I tried adding a break in the if statement and the code worked but only for the first input.

Comment: You shouldn't do `require` in a a loop.

Comment: `$_POST` will only work with input types.

Comment: Not sure why you have a loop here at all. Doing a "not" comparison here `while(!isset($_POST["submit_$num"])){` will cause the loop to be infinite.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, oh, I totally forgot to take that out, thanks!, and thank you for the $_POST info

Comment: @tadman I'm doing this website for a school project and sadly I don't have to time to learn a new framework as the website is almost done . I'll defiantly check out Laravel when I get some free time after I finish the project, thanks!

Comment: @JayBlanchard about the loop being infinite, what I was trying to do is loop for every button that wasn't pressed and when the num arrives to the right button the loop stops, _btw, I added `$num=$num +1;` to the loop._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done without loop on submit, using array syntax for input names

Replace `name=\"id_$num\"` with `name=\"id[$num]\"`, `name=\"status_$num\"` with `name=\"status[$num]\"`, and `name=\"submit_$num\"` with `name=\"submit[$num]\"`. So you code would be like this:

```
echo     "<input type=\"hidden\"name=\"id[$num]\" 
        value=".$row['idSales']."><tr><td>".$row['idSales'].
        "</td><td>". $username.
        "</td><td>". $row['product'].
        "</td><td>". $row['productAmount'].
        "</td><td>". $row['dateOfPurchase'].
        "</td><td>". $row['userAddress'].
        "</td><td><a href=\"$eLink\">". $eLink .
        "</a></td><td>
        <input type=\"text\" name=\"status[$num]\" class=\"input\" value=".$row['productStatus']. ">
        <input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit[$num]\" value=\"submit\" class=\"button\"></td></tr>" ;
```

Then `$_POST['submit']` will contain array with one element `[$num => 'submit']`.  `$_POST['id']` and  `$_POST['status']` are arrays too. You can easily get id and status:

```
$num = array_shift(array_keys($_POST['submit']));
$id = $_POST['id'][$num];
$status = $_POST['status'][$num];
```

If `$row['idSales']` is an integer and unique, you could also rid of the hidden input "id" and use $row['idSales'] as keys instead $num. So the first fragment would be:

```
echo    "<tr><td>".$row['idSales'].
        "</td><td>". $username.
        "</td><td>". $row['product'].
        "</td><td>". $row['productAmount'].
        "</td><td>". $row['dateOfPurchase'].
        "</td><td>". $row['userAddress'].
        "</td><td><a href=\"$eLink\">". $eLink .
        "</a></td><td>
        <input type=\"text\" name=\"status[" . $row['idSales'] . "]\" class=\"input\" value=".$row['productStatus']. ">
        <input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit[" . $row['idSales'] . "]\" value=\"submit\" class=\"button\"></td></tr>" ;
```

and the second

```
$id = array_shift(array_keys($_POST['submit']));
$status = $_POST['status'][$id];
```

Comment: thank you so much! yes my id is an integer and unique, what do I need to replace in the code to not use $name?

Comment: I've completed my answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your while() loop should break if you encounter a valid $*POST["submit*$num"] ?

$num is not increased within the while() loop: its value stays at -1, !isset() remains valid, and so you have an endless loop

I suggest your table to be rewritten as

```
echo "... <input type='submit' name 'btnSubmit' value='$num'> ..." ;
```

Then you can directly query $_POST['btnSubmit'] , without the endless loop required.

On your question on $_POST vs. non-input fields: no, you need at least a hidden input field to have it show up in $_POST[]

*edit* : try this sample code in http://phpfiddle.org/ :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php
if ( isset($_POST['btnSubmit']) )
{
    echo "<P>In previous run, submitted value " . $_POST[ 'entry' . $_POST['btnSubmit'] ] . "</P> \r\n" ;
}
else
    echo "<P>No submit in previous run ...</P> \r\n" ;    
?>

   <form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
      <input type=text name="entry1" value="123">
      <input type=submit name="btnSubmit" value="1"><br/>
      <input type=text name="entry2" value="456">
      <input type=submit name="btnSubmit" value="2">
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

You can edit both text fields, then click 1 submit button: the script will echo the corresponding updated value

*edit 2* :

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function mySubmit(submitValue)
{   
   try
   {
      // store selected submit value in hidden INPUT 
      document.getElementById('submitID').value = submitValue ;

      // manually submit the form
      document.getElementById('formID').submit() ;
   }
   catch(err)
   {
       alert(err.message) ;
   }    
 }
</script>    
</head>
<body>

<?php
if ( isset($_POST['btnSubmit']) )
   echo "<P>In previous run, you submitted value " . $_POST[ 'entry' . $_POST['btnSubmit'] ] . "</P> \r\n" ;
else
   echo "<P>No submit in previous run ...</P> \r\n" ;
?>

   <form id='formID' name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
      <input type=text name="entry1" value="123">
      <button onClick="mySubmit(1);">Submit me !</button><br/>
      <input type=text name="entry2" value="456">
      <button onClick="mySubmit(2);">Submit me !</button><br/>

      <input type=hidden id='submitID' name='btnSubmit'>    
   </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Now, this is a quick-and-dirty method - so depending on your complete case, you could consider setting up an AJAX call

Comment: if I use the same name for every button and/or input(status), when I use $_POST how will my code know which input was changed?

Comment: because the VALUE of that control changes : suppose row 1 has 'btnSubmit' value "1", row 2 has 'btnSubmit' value "2", .... If you click the submit button for row 365, $_POST["btnSubmit"] will contain 365. So then you know $POST["status_365"] contains the submitted value.
It might seem odd to redeclare an input field - but you're redeclaring an input *name*, not an input *ID*.  Check out https://www.techrepublic.com/article/handling-multiple-submits-in-a-single-form-with-php/ , chapter BRANCHING WITH SWITCH/ASE

Comment: is it possible to do without the value attribute? I want to buttons to say "submit" and not 1,2,3...

Comment: I just edited my answer with sample code, so I missed your comment :-) Yes, you can: create an <INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN> in your form. Replace each row's submit button by a regular button that calls a JS function "mySubmit(<?php echo $num; ?>) : this function takes the argument, writes it to the hidden variable , then fires the form submit. Check edit 2.

But - then you are coming close to AJAX territory; might want to check if that's a better fit for your entire solution.